# How to install bower dependencies using npm install?

Tags: npm, bower

I want npm install to install the bower dependencies as well. I have a bower.json file containing frontend packages and there is package.json file which contains the backend packages. After i run npm install, node_modules are installed whereas the dependencies mentioned in bower.json file are not installed.

I don't want to use bower install rather I want to do all this with npm install command.

Comment: `npm` cannot do this and it will probably never be supported. If those frontend modules are in the npm registry then you should be able to move them to `package.json` so that you can install them with `npm`.

Answer (score 9):

It's quite simple. If you have bower listed in `package.json` as dependency you may add `postinstall` script to your `package.json` as follows:

```
"scripts": {
  "postinstall": "bower install"
}
```

and running `npm install` will launch also bower install automatically